# Nested Spinners?

Tags: android, spinner

How do I use spinners as an item for a spinner?
Probably not really possible since I couldn't find anything on Slack or other sites.

Somehow I managed to put a spinner as an item for a parent spinner using a custom layout, but of course, after selecting any item parent spinner gets my selection and sets its value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/standard_10_dp"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_250_dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Spinner
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/childSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/standard_5_dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_16"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Parent Category"
    android:id="@+id/tv_"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

next thing I thought of was trying to prevent the parent spinner from using the selection, without success.

Is this even possible or how else could I achieve this behaviour ?

Comment: Have you manage to show spinner as item of spinner?

Comment: Somehow, as you can see in the XML I made the spinner `invisible | gone` and I tried to use `performClick()` on it after..because if I keep it `visible` the whole dropdown of parent spinner won't be visible *weird*